# #1054 - Unknown column 'Owner' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have query result for column `LOWER(Owner)` from `SELECT LOWER(Owner) FROM ...`

But I want this `LOWER(Owner)` to stand as `name` but my query gives me an error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'Owner' in 'field list'`

```
SELECT LOWER(Owner) AS name FROM (
    SELECT LOWER(Owner) FROM ...
) AS buyers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the subquery doesn't have a column `owner`. So add alias like this:

```
SELECT owner FROM (
    SELECT LOWER(Owner) AS Owner FROM ...
) AS buyers
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the alias in the subquery:

```
SELECT name
FROM (SELECT LOWER(Owner) as name FROM ...
     ) AS buyers
```